# Is it possible to start the GRASS GUI from R?

Tags: r, grass-gis, grass-7.0

I am using the [rgrass7](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgrass7/index.html) package in R in order to work with GRASS GIS. After having set the needed enviornment variables, I can now launch a GRASS session from R and and work on my GRASS data using RStudio.

I would like to work with the GRASS GUI and the rgrass7 interface the same way as when I start R (RStudio) from the GRASS terminal ([Using RStudio in a GRASS GIS session](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/R_statistics/rgrass7#Using_RStudio_in_a_GRASS_GIS_session)). The only difference is that I would like to work mainly in RStudio and only open the GRASS GUI only when needed.

**Is it possible to launch the GRASS GUI from R within a running GRASS session?**

When I try the sollowing command, the GUI does not open and I get a warning message:

```
> execGRASS("g.gui", ui="wxpython")
Warning message:
running command 'g.gui.exe ui=wxpython' had status 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to launch the GRASS GUI from R within a running GRASS session.

It did not work because the environment variables where not correctly set. Modifiying the environment variables as follows solved the problem:

```
# Set PYTHONPATH
Sys.setenv(PYTHONPATH = paste0("C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\grass\\grass-7.0.3\\etc\\python;C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\grass\\grass-7.0.3\\gui\\wxpython"))

# Set PYTHONHOME
Sys.setenv(PYTHONHOME = "C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27")

# Set PATHS for case of OSGEO4W
newPath <- "C:\\OSGEO4~1\\bin"
Sys.setenv("PATH" = paste(newPath, Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=.Platform$path.sep))
newPath <- "C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\grass\\grass-7.0.3\\lib"
Sys.setenv("PATH" = paste(newPath, Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=.Platform$path.sep))
newPath <- "C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\grass\\grass-7.0.3\\bin"
Sys.setenv("PATH" = paste(newPath, Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=.Platform$path.sep))
newPath <- "C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\Scripts"
Sys.setenv("PATH" = paste(newPath, Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=.Platform$path.sep))

# Set GISBASE
  # (directory where GRASS lives)
Sys.setenv(GISBASE = "C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\grass\\grass-7.0.3")

# Set GRASS_PYTHON
  # (To override Python executable)
Sys.setenv(GRASS_PYTHON = "C:\\OSGEO4~1\\bin\\python.exe")
```

Although, not all the variable setting might have been directly related to solving the problem.

But now, the GUI can be lauchned by simply calling:

```
execGRASS("g.gui", ui="wxpython")
```